# What is the default cipher list set to in courier-imap

Tags: imap

I've been trying to find the default TLS_CIPHER_LIST for courier imap when the setting isn't defined in imapd-ssl.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Courier documentation](https://www.courier-mta.org/couriertls.html) describes "TLS_CIPHER_LIST" but doesn't mention a default. [A look at the source code reveals that the current default is](https://github.com/svarshavchik/courier-libs/blob/531c5ca6c1290dfc036f6149199cb9c19ba23ab1/tcpd/libcouriertls.c#L829) `TLSv1:HIGH:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!EXP:!NULL:!aNULL@STRENGTH`. If your version of Courier is built against OpenSSL (in contrast to the packages shipping with Debian/Ubuntu [which are built](https://packages.debian.org/buster/courier-base) [against GnuTLS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/courier-base)) you can expand that to a full list of cipher names by running the following command:

```
$ openssl ciphers 'TLSv1:HIGH:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!EXP:!NULL:!aNULL@STRENGTH'
```

Example output from an Ubuntu 20.04 machine with OpenSSL 1.1.1f:

```
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384:ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA:RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384:DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384:ECDHE-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384:RSA-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384:DHE-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384:PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384:PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM8:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM:DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM8:DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM:ECDHE-ECDSA-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-DSS-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA:RSA-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384:RSA-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-PSK-AES256-CCM8:DHE-PSK-AES256-CCM:RSA-PSK-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-PSK-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-CCM8:AES256-CCM:ARIA256-GCM-SHA384:PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384:PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305:PSK-AES256-CCM8:PSK-AES256-CCM:PSK-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:CAMELLIA256-SHA256:SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA:SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA:RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA:DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256:ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA:RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256:DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256:ECDHE-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256:RSA-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256:DHE-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256:PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256:PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM:DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM8:DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM:ECDHE-ECDSA-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA:RSA-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-PSK-AES128-CCM8:DHE-PSK-AES128-CCM:RSA-PSK-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-PSK-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-CCM8:AES128-CCM:ARIA128-GCM-SHA256:PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256:PSK-AES128-CCM8:PSK-AES128-CCM:PSK-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:CAMELLIA128-SHA256:SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA:SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA:RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA:DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA:AES128-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA
```

Note that [this list depends on your OpenSSL version](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ciphers.html) so make sure you run this command on your mail server machine. It's a good idea to look through this list carefully. Even on my up-to-date system this list contains quite a few ciphers that have to be considered weak.

Comment: So how do you disable all the unsafe ciphers in courier then?

Comment: @rubo77 you have to modify the `TLS_CIPHER_LIST` string as described in the [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ciphers.html). For example you might chose to disable the `ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384` cipher [to avoid potential implementation weaknesses](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/210072/why-does-ssl-labs-now-consider-cbc-suites-weak) by adding `:!ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384` to the string. If you are not a security expert online tests like the one provided by [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) can provide some guidance.

Comment: So can I use `openssl ciphers 'TLSv1.3:HIGH:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!EXP:!NULL:!aNULL@STRENGTH'` to get the latest TLSv3 ciphers and add them in the old Debian 8 server which does not support TLS 1.3 yet?

Comment: [Support for TLS 1.3 has been introduced with OpenSSL 1.1.1](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/TLS1.3). Debian 10 is the first release [that comes with v1.1.1d](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=openssl&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). You cannot enable ciphers that aren't supported by your version of OpenSSL. Run `openssl ciphers ALL` to get a list of the ciphers your version supports.

Comment: sure, But my Idea was to generate the full list in a Debian buster system and use it in Debian jessie like: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/4ea6d21e83ae3f0033c8637106487a3e

Comment: Might be worth opening a separate question for that. I'm not exactly sure what you want to do but it sounds like that goes beyond the OP's question.

Comment: OpenSSL v1.1.1 on Debian 10 would expand "TLSv1.3" to a list of TLSv1.3 ciphers but none of these ciphers will work with OpenSSL <=1.1.0 on Debian 8 since it doesn't support TLSv1.3. To quote the [OpenSSL Wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/TLS1.3#Differences_with_TLS1.2_and_below): "TLSv1.3 is a major rewrite of the specification. [...] A brief, incomplete, summary of some things that you are likely to notice follows:
- There are new ciphersuites that only work in TLSv1.3. The old ciphersuites cannot be used for TLSv1.3 connections and the new ones cannot be used in TLSv1.2 and below."

Comment: I just noticed I mentioned the SSL Labs test above which only for HTTPS servers. You can use [ImmuniWeb's test](https://www.immuniweb.com/ssl/) to test your mail server's TLS configuration (specify the server as mail.example.com:25 or mail.example.com:993).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.courier-mta.org/couriertls.html sais:

> TLS_CIPHER_LIST=cipherlist
>
> - Optionally set the list of protocol ciphers to be used. See OpenSSL's documentation for more information.

So I think it takes the defined ciphers in openssl then.

Note: apart from the Ciphers list, you probably want to set

```
TLS_PROTOCOL="TLSv1.2"
```

This will turn off TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1

Whether TLSv1.2 works depends on whether your openssl library  is recent enough to support TLS1.2

In case you want to disable TLS v1.0 and TLS v1.1 in your SSL certs, you have to set it in your webbrowser, e.g. for `nginx`, see this link:
https://libre-software.net/tls-nginx/#tls